# VBA Saving Excel Sheet as a PDF in the same File's Directory

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to save the Excel file as a PDF in VBA but was told that this is not sufficient for when sending the Excel file to another person. I will have to save it as a PDF in the same directory as the Excel sheet itself. 
How does this work? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: For the path you can use something like `ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pdfNameHere.pdf"`

Comment: Will try this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Where would I place that here?: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testpdf.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

Comment: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\testpdf.pdf"

Comment: I get the error "Document not saved. The document may be open or an error may have been encountered when saving" I also forgot to mention the pdf should open after being saved.

Comment: Did you include the rest of the line?

Comment: Yes, got the same error. This is what I typed: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\testpdf.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

Comment: Has the ActiveWorkbook been saved?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SaveAsPdf()

File_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
   Filename = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, ".") - 1)
End If

File_name = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Filename & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=File_name, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```